# PyInstaller: Single-file executable doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

`PS C:\Users\user> pyinstaller onefile                                                                                                                                                           Traceback (most recent call last): File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 107, in run parser = generate_parser() ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 78, in generate_parser import PyInstaller.building.build_main ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 35, in <module> from PyInstaller.depend import bindepend ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 26, in <module> from PyInstaller.depend import dylib, utils ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\utils.py", line 33, in <module> from PyInstaller.depend import bytecode ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bytecode.py", line 95, in <module> _call_function_bytecode = bytecode_regex(rb""" ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bytecode.py", line 60, in bytecode_regex pattern = re.sub( ^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\re.py", line 190, in sub return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bytecode.py", line 62, in <lambda> lambda m: _instruction_to_regex(m[1].decode()), ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bytecode.py", line 40, in _instruction_to_regex return re.escape(bytes([dis.opmap[x]])) ~~~~~~~~~^^^ KeyError: 'CALL_FUNCTION'` I'm trying to create a single-file executable for Windows from a Python application, using pyinstaller, but the commend doesn't run and

Answer (score 1):

I honestly do not know what that error is. All I can say is that
the command for making a single .exe file with pyinstaller is:

```
pyinstaller --onefile <filename>
```

For example `pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py`

I did a quick search and found this in [pyinstaller: create one executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898511/pyinstaller-create-one-executable-file)

What you have done is `pyinstaller onefile`, which is the same as telling pyinstaller to create the executable using a file called onefile. <s>When the program doesn't find the file 'onefile' it will not work, and it throws an error.</s>

Comment: the error is when i try to making a single .exe file with pyinstaller the command doesn't working and giving me that tracback above

Comment: so im traying to know wher is the problem to fix it but i doesn't find it , so if you help me to find the problem i will be grateful

Comment: Could you update your question or just comment here with the output of calling 'python --version' and 'pyinstaller --version'?
I don't know how to interpret the traceback so I can only try the versions you have and see if any of them or a combination of them are the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This was addressed here:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6950

Looks like it's been merged in so make sure your PyInsaller version is 5.6 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake when you writing arguments can you give more details? or if you can't use PyInsaller on shell you can use this library with pyinstaller gui https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Answer (score 0):

in CDM console run "set GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH=quiet"

Comment: Please post some more information about this. Don't just post code.